# Flutter: Add some widgets in between ListView.builder and ScrollView without using shrinkWrap

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to add some non constrained widgets in between ListView.builder and ScrollView without using shrinkWrap: true? I need something like this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Padding(
    padding: somePadding,
    child: Center(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: someConstaints,
        child: Card(
          ListView.builder(someBuilder);
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

And I can make it with `shrinkWrap: true` to get something like this:

[image of that I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQmgB.png)

The list is inside a centered `Card` and both the card and the list are scrolled as the whole `Scaffold` body.

The problem is, the list is expected to be really large so `shrinkWrap` will have noticeable effect on performance. Is there any way to achieve the same without loosing lazy building of the list?

Comment: Its a suggestion, if your list is really long, why not just render a list of list tiles instead of scroll able card +  whole screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do something close to that I've wanted with Slivers. It's easy to change `ScrollView` to `CustomScrollView` and `ListView.builder` to `SliverList` with `SliverChildBuilderDelegate`, the problem is that everything in between should be Slivers as well.

1. `Padding` is easy as it has its Sliver counterpart `SliverPadding`.
2. `Center` and `ConstrainedBox` are more difficult as they seem not to have any Sliver alternatives. So I ended up achieving their effect by using `LayoutBuilder` (`SliverLayoutBuilder` is also an option) and manually calculating horizontal padding based on the viewport size and the list width I want.
3. No solution for `Card` surrounding the whole list though, so instead I ended up using separate `Card` for each list child.

So in the end I get something like this:

```
LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverPadding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: somePadding,
                  horizontal: (constraints.maxWidth - desiredListWidth) / 2),
              sliver: SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(/*some list child with card code*/),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
);
```

It works, but not exactly that I wanted and it has some limitations. So I'm still hoping someone has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use silvers to overcome this problem and also using silvers instead of shrinkwrap enhances performance of app

Comment: I've looked into Slivers already and it doesn't seem to be able to solve the problem. CustomScrollView needs all its children to be Slivers, but I need regular widgets (Card, Padding, Center). I can use SliverToBoxAdaptor for them, but then, I can't use Sliver for my list as it is nested into regular widgets again.

I haven't understood Slivers completely, so correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: inside customScrollView you can use SliverToBoxAdapter() which accepts normal widgets like container,Card,Padding etc

Comment: Yes, but then I won't be able to add SliverList as a child of it, because it will expect regular widgets.

Comment: I meant add silver list as child first. The n use silver to box adapter to use whichever widget you want

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is having this problems they can use separated List View builder as it has another builder for some widgets you want to insert in between your widgets.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).